# Flexbox equal width problems

Tags: flexbox

Dear fellow stackoverflowers,

I'm having a peculiar problem I can't seem to find the solution for.

I'm trying to apply the width of the largest div to the smaller divs, so that they appear equal in width, through flexboxing. Unfortunately, all the solutions so far have been futile efforts. Do you have any idea why the different divs in the example I've linked to won't display the same width as the largest element? I know the boxes get their width from the content, but I just can't seem to make them behave the way I want.

HTML

```
            <section id="contact" class="wrapper bgfixed">
            <div>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <div  id="contactholder">


        <a href="#">
        <div>
            <h1 class="icon-mail"></h1>
            <h2>EMAIL</h2>
            <p>someonesprofessionalemail@gmail.com</p>
          </div>
        </a>  

        <a href="#">
        <div>
            <h1 class="icon-old-phone"></h1>
            <h2>TELEPHONE</h2>
            <p>39 88 49 92 91</p>
          </div>
        </a>  

        <a href="#">
        <div>
            <h1 class="icon-facebook2"></h1>
            <h2>FACEBOOK</h2>
            <p>www.facebooooooooooooooooooook.com/snowman</p>
          </div>
        </a>  
         <a href="#">
        <div>
            <h1 class="icon-soundcloud"></h1>
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
            <p>www.loremipsumyesyesyesblahblabhlabh.com</p>
          </div>
        </a>  


            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
    a{text-decoration: none;}
    #contact
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 82vh;
        color: whitesmoke;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #34495e;
    }
    #contactholder
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        font-size: 80%;
    }
    #contactholder div
    {
        flex: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }

    #contactholder div h1
    {
        padding: 3rem;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: linear-gradient(white, 1%, #3498db);
        border-radius: 100rem;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px grey;
        transition: 0.3s;
        margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
    }

    #contactholder a:hover h1
    {
        background-image: linear-gradient(white, 1%, #00A4EB);
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px;


    }
```

Hoping for some brilliant minds!

Best wishes,
Lodott1

Comment: This is a good question, I think. However, this code doesn't look like the shortest possible code you could have. I'm no expert in HTML, so I could easily be wrong, but please try to trim out all unnecessary bits of the code. For example, I don't think you need the styling of the links inside the divs in your CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. I tried removing your suggestions, but the results are still bad. The divs inside the #contactholder are still showing as their individual sizes based on their content.

Comment: Oh, no, I'm not saying that it'll fix your problem -- I'm saying that it'll help diagnose the problem.

Comment: My bad, sorry for confusing.. I'll let you know if I stumble upon the solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I found that when changing the

#contactholder div
to 
#contactholder a, it started behaving a bit better. But now, content is overflowing from the largest div.